# Hartl Rails Tutorial Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason while running the spec test, the updated navigation dropdown menu layout from Bootstrap  fails to render(i.e it doesn't show "Account") upon signing in. Here is my authentication_pages_spec:
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title',text: user.name) }

        it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
        it { should have_link('Profile',  href: users_path(path)) }
        it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

        describe "followed by signout" do
            before { click_link "Sign out" }
            it { should have_link('Sign in') }
        end
    end
  end
end
```

**Header Layout**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
      <% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: is `signed_in?` returning false by any change?

Comment: please add `sessions_controller.rb` and `sessions_helper.rb` code to  your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your app/assets/application.js file.

bootstrap needs to be listed directly underneath jquery.

`//= require jquery

     //= require bootstrap

     //= require jquery_ujs

     //= require turbo links

     //= require_tree .`